# What does this sentence mean? “千万比我不要更有格调！”

Tags: simplified-characters

您好！Hello!
我是中文学习的初心者！：）I just started learning Chinese and yes, it is quite daunting haha.

我偶然发现此句子。“**千万比我不要更有格调！**”。（*可能这个句子写的人不是中国人！*）

我不明白意思的这句子。请帮助我明白！
多谢！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *千万比我不要更有格调*

The correct grammar is 千万不要比我更有格调 (absolutely don't be more stylish than me)

千万 - absolutely

不要 - don't

比我 - compare to me

更 - more

有格调 - stylish

Comment: 多谢多谢！：）Thank you so much for the explanation! Would this sound more or less natural if spoken? Or does it sound totally fob-like? ：）

Comment: It is a complete sentence, but with limited context, we don't know why the speaker says that and to whom